# Click function into click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I thought that if I put one click function into click function it was only proceeding the second click function if it was clicked, but when I click the first the codes for second one is running... I thought that if i clicked the second one it should have run the codes. 
I mean when I clicked the second one then the codes are visible and doing as they should do, but If click like first function 3 times without to click the second and suddenly click on the second, it is behaving like the codes have run three times.

```
$(".click1").click(function () {
    alert("hej");
    $(".click2").
    function ({
        alert("bye");
    });
});
```

My intention is to only make the second click to run when it is really clicked and not run the codes if I click the first one!

To be more clear. When I click first, it says hej and if I click three time then it will say hej 3x but when I suddenly click click2 it showing bye three times but I only clicked once.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening? and How i can prevent this to happen?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT!!

```
function click_back() {

        current_question_for_answer.splice(0,1);
        $("#tillbaka_question").fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
        $("#tillbaka_question").off("click");
        $(".questions").hide();
        $(".containing_boxes").show();

        $(".answered_box").remove();

        var numbers_of_answered_question = history.length - 1;
        for (var i = numbers_of_answered_question; i > -1; i--) { 
            current_question.push(i);
            $(".containing_boxes").prepend('<div class="answered_box">'+i+'</div>');
            $("div.containing_boxes > div:nth-child("+history.length+")").css("background-color", "green");
            $(".containing_boxes").hide();
            $(".containing_boxes").fadeIn(100);
        }

        $("div.containing_boxes > div").not(":last-child").click(answered_box);
        $("div.containing_boxes > div:nth-child("+history.length+")").click(function () {
```

$("div.containing_boxes > div:nth-child("+history.length+")").click(function () { }) this function should only work if I click it. I can not seperate this code in two new function. If I do it, then the whole system will stop working.....

Comment: `$(".click2").function({ alert("bye"); });` Is not valid JavaScript. What exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, his is what you are after:

```
$(".click1").click(function () { alert("hej"); });
$(".click2").click(function () { alert("bye"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you clicked on click1 3 times, the click event on click2 is 3x created. Thats why it will alert 'bye' 3 times.

Comment: Yes, but how do I prevent this to happen?

Comment: make a variable that is set to true when you click, also then add a `if ( true )` condition to the function

Comment: take a look at @Nept hes answer, that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first click is attaching another click handler which means the second click will fire multiple times, so every time you click it you will get a lot of "bye"s. To avoid this, you can simply set a variable like `var isClicked = 0` on load, and then before attaching the handler to click2, check if `isClicked == 0`, if true then set `isClicked = 1` so it only works once

```
var isClicked = 0;

$(".click1").click(function () {
    alert("hej");
    if ( isClicked == 0 ) {
        isClicked = 1;
        $(".click2").
        function ({
            alert("bye");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So, what's the problem the OP is facing and how does your solution solve it? Your answer would be *much* more helpful if you provided an explanation as well.

Comment: @FelixKling maybe, but it's fairly simple, anyone who knows what an if statement is should be able to tell what i'm doing. I edited it anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should **Unbind** click event before **binding** New click event

```
$(".click1").click(function () {
    alert("hej");
    $(".click2").unbind('click');
    $(".click2").bind('click',function (){
        alert("bye");
    });
});
```

## [Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BArsr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var click1 = false;

$(".click1").click(function () {
    alert("hej");
    click1 = true;
});

$(".click2").click(function() {
    if (click1 === true) {
        alert("bye");
        click1 = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I can use that method but the problem I get is that I have some value I need from first click function. taking those values and calling click 2. If I separate both cliks function, Then the whole system wont work....... :(

Comment: please, check my edit! I have put my orginal code there

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click 1st button, You are registering click event for the 2nd button, so if you click 1st button 5x then 2nd button click event will be registered 5x

The solution is that 
You make sure that every time you click 1st button you unregister click event for 2nd button, then register it again

Comment: Is it possible to do it when I can click function into click function, without making two separate functions

Comment: See the solution of@ Manwal,  it's exactly what I meant, however Bind() and unbind() are deprecated as far as I remember,  so use on() and off() functions